# How to implement both horizantal and vertical scroll in tableview in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am new in swift and I am not able to scroll tableview horizontally for that I used Scrollview but it still not scrolling 
[image]

But It is only showing

[image]

Not scrolling horizontally can somebody please help me. My structure is like this

[image]

Did somebody know how to convert this code to swift

```
UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, x, x, x) style:...]

[scrollView addSubview:tableView];

// Set the size of your table to be the size of it's contents 
// (since the outer scroll view will handle the scrolling).
CGRect tableFrame = tableView.frame;
tableFrame.size.height = tableView.contentSize.height;
tableFrame.size.width = tableView.contentSize.width; // if you would allow horiz scrolling
tableView.frame = tableFrame;

// Set the content size of your scroll view to be the content size of your 
// table view + whatever else you have in the scroll view.
// For the purposes of this example, I'm assuming the table view is in there alone.
scrollView.contentSize = tableView.contentSize;
```

Comment: TableView is for horizontal scrolling. And in the above UI, it seems that you didn't apply the constraints properly.

Comment: For the horizontal scrolling, you can use `UICollectionView`

Comment: @Niraj  its both horizontally and vertically

Comment: Hope this helps. https://medium.com/@suj9763/vertical-and-horizontal-scroll-design-using-tableview-and-collectionview-container-and-child-450776e328fd

Comment: If you want to create spreadsheet like layout take a look at: https://github.com/keshiim/ZMJGanttChart and https://github.com/manirajaa/AssesmentCollection There are lot of controls https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=spreadsheet

Comment: @RushabhShah Do not want to used collection view because Applicationid is I set it on index path.row == 0 and for other data is from server it is not possible using collection view

Comment: Then you have only 1 option used 3rd party library which Niraj has mention.

Answer (score 0):

I have done the same as this.
Please find my screenshot[image: Here I am using a fixed width for tableView]

Comment: How you are scrolling tableview horizontally